# Use the definition to prove for all natural number m, 4m+ 7 odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

The Definition that I was given for an odd number is: $m$ is odd if there exist an integer $k$ such that $m =2k+1$.

I'm lost on how to prove this, what I have so far is this

$4m+7 = 4i+7$

$=(4i+6)+1$

When giving an explanation I'm not sure if I should say $4i+6$ is an integer (even) and $+1$ is odd.

Comment: $4m+7=2(2m+3)+1$, $2m+3$ is an integer so it fits the form $2k+1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When giving an explanation I'm not sure if I should say $4i+6$ is an integer (even) and $+1$ is odd.

No, this is *not* what you want to say!  You are told to *use the definition*, so you need to use the the definition.  That is, the *only* way you can prove a number is odd (in this context) is by proving it satisfies the definition: that is, there exists an integer $k$ such that the number is $2k+1$.

That mean you need to find some integer $k$ such that $4m+7=2k+1$.  In other words, you want to solve that equation for $k$ and show that the value of $k$ you obtain is indeed an integer.  Can you see a way to do that?

(Also, when writing a proof, you want to be very clear and precise about all your notation.  What do you mean when you write $4n+7=4i+7$?  Where did these variables $n$ and $i$ come from?  The problem statement, at least in the title of your post, uses $m$ instead, so you should probably use $m$.  If you use a different variable, you should explain what it means and how it is related to $m$.)